# gi.repository/Python3 example for Indicate?

Tags: python, indicator, messaging-menu

Is there a `gi.repository` (and Python 3) example for `Indicate`?

I am having trouble following the [example at Ubuntu App Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/messaging-menu/).

Specifically if I do:

```
from gi.repository import Indicate
mm = indicate.indicate_server_ref_default()
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Indicate' object has no attribute 'indicate_server_ref_default'
```

Not sure if I'm missing a library (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 but will move to 13.04 when released) or getting the API wrong... or both!

Not having a Python API is frustrating - I assume this is because the Python library front-end dynamically calls underlying C?  Is there a way to generate the Python API documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use this:

`Indicate.Server.ref_default()`

to get the default server reference.

For documentation you can run `pydoc3 gi.repository.Indicate`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now further along!  For the documentation, I ran the command you mentioned and got very little in terms of useful API.